# Playwright eval javascript in context of iframe window

Tags: javascript, iframe, eval, e2e-testing, playwright

I have a sandbox on my page that I'm trying to run some tests in.

```
const iframe = await page.frameLocator('#scripting-sandbox');
iframe.evaluate(test.toString())
```

This obviously doesn't work, iframe has no method evaluate. What's the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: did you ever solve this issue?